# PHP MySQL: JOIN vs. FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, join

I have a many to many relationship, and need to decide whether to create another table for it - or to store the relationship in a table with a string (CSV)... in other words:

EXAMPLE:
tbl_Team
tbl_Fan

(optional): tbl_fanTeam
I want to be able to pick all fans of a team, or pick an individual fan and see all teams that they are a fan of.

What is the best method in my SQL call, is it with using JOIN with a 3rd relational table (tbl_fanteam) or to place all the values in one of the existing two tables?  Hope this makes sense...

Comment: No need for the PHP tag, you might be coding in PHP but this question has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `JOIN ... ON a.x = b.y` the database can take advantage of indexes to speed up the query.

When you use `FIND_IN_SET` the indexes cannot be used so it will require a full scan. This will be slow if your tables have many rows.

Comment: @Shackrock: Indexes allow the database to find a row more quickly in certain situations. Having suitable indexes can improve the speed of the query. See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) for more information about how MySQL uses indexes.  Quote from manual: *MySQL uses indexes for these operations: [...] To retrieve rows from other tables when performing joins.*